# What files and libraries do I need for OpenGL and controls

Tags: opengl

I am starting a 3D game, however I find OpenGL file system very confusing. OpenGL package doesn't have  one file, other package doesn't have another, so I need a summary of what files do I need to start playing with 3D. It would be good if it included keyboard and mouse controls.

Shortened question: Where can I get all files for OpenGl 4.0 and integrated controls libary?

Comment: Using windows by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenGL comes as standard with the windows development environments (both visual studio and msys/mingw). What you want are two other components to help you get started with OpenGL 4.0: an extension loader library, and a simple toolkit to set up a window and get events.

Use glew or gl3w for the former, and freeglut or glfw for the latter.

Comment: Or try the [sdl](http://www.libsdl.org).

Comment: Any tutorials on how to use them? I do know how to link them and etc. ofcourse.